# Execution default of goal com.github.tntim96:jscover-file-maven-plugin:1.0.19:jscover failed: jscoverage_serializeCoverageToJSON is not defined

Tags: jscoverage

I am trying to implement JSCover to check the coverage of my code [js files].I have added jscover-file-maven-plugin to the pom.xml of my app. When I try to run maven install on the app, my build is getting failed with following message:

```
[INFO] --- jscover-file-maven-plugin:1.0.19:jscover (default) @ webUi ---
[INFO] Ran JSCover instrumentation
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.tntim96:jscover-file-maven-      plugin:1.0.19:jscover (default) on project webUi: Execution default of goal   com.github.tntim96:jscover-file-maven-plugin:1.0.19:jscover failed: jscoverage_serializeCoverageToJSON is not defined"
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here?enter code here

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like any tests were run. If you're not sure of the configuration, you can compare with the working example at https://github.com/tntim96/JSCover-samples. You can also post your configuration and directory structure.

You can try the 1.0.20-SNAPSHOT, which has more logging (but requires Java 8), with the following:

```
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>Sonatype repository</id>
    <name>Sonatype's Maven repository</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```